# Save operation - File is not externally editable

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser and it is working fine.

```
File a = new File(strSavepath);
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(a);
```

Problem is that I am unable to edit the saved file manually using Notepad or other editors unless I run garbage collector manually using VisualVM.

Am I missing something or someone else has also observed this behavior?

Comment: What is the code you are using to do the save, after the user has selected the filename to save to?

Comment: I am using FileOutputStream to write bytes received from JTextArea. Finally block is present to ensure that stream is closed.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Could you please edit the question to include more code. Then we might be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: Just because the stream is closed does not necessarily mean the VM has released the file handle, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

*"when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"* (S.H.)

You must have an *infinite loop*. Debugging, logging might help convincing oneself. Or otherwise having mixed up the file path for another one.

(Also to put it clear: `a` is the directory, not the file itself.)

Answer (score 0):

As @TomG points, closing the stream means the stream (i.e., if you don't use the file any more, your application) no longer has a handle on the file, but that doesn't mean VisualVM releases the handle too (although it should, I think). To check if, for some bug or similar reason, VisualVM is keeping the handle on the file after your application has released it, run your application out of VisualVM, and then try to save the file manually. If it's not yet possible, you're leaving the stream open. Otherwise, you can use [Windows handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) or similar tool to determine if what's actually keeping the handle in the file is VisualVM or another application.